# PineScript: plot a line with custom values

Tags: pine-script

I'm a newbie and I'd like to create a simple indicator I update every day with my numeric values and that plots one line chart.
I tried this but it plots 3 single separate lines that don't have neither start nor end.

Could you help me please?

```
study("Study")

8may22 = 3
9may22 = 1
10may22 = 2

plot(8may22) 
plot(9may22) 
plot(10may22)
```

Answer (score 1):

Plot can "plot" a Series. So you need to build a Series which happens automatically.

Pine runs your code on every bar (this is what usually wraps the newbies' heads around) and most importantly it runs your code on every tick on the current bar (when you sit in front of Tradingview and just watch the chart).

When your code sets a variable in a run, Pine will automatically save the value from the run, and append it to a Series behind the scenes.

So the only thing you need is to do is to set a single variable (which is a Series, you just don't realize it) to a value and Pine will record the value of that variable in every run, making you a Series.

```
my_variable = close * 2 - open / high //random calculated nonsense
plot(my_variable)
```

Apply this study to a chart (low timeframe) and watch how the plotted line will move around on the current bar as it is being constantly recalculated and repainted. When the bar is closed, and no more data is being added to it, the plot will "finalize" there and a new bar will be opened.

Your example of `8may22 = 3` worked the same way, it was setting the variable to '3' in every run and Pine saved that value in every run, effectively creating a line with a constant value.

UPDATE:
Here is a simple code I hope it helps to understand some internals of Pine. Apply this script to a 12 month USDCHF chart. With the 12 month setting you will have a chart that has only a few bars:

```
// © karatedog
//@version=5
indicator("Custom series", overlay = false)
custom_series = bar_index < 15 ? 3.0 : 5.3
plot(custom_series)
```

You will see the plot's value is 3.3 at bar #0 and it will change to 5.3 at bar #15, whatever time frame you chose (as long as it has 15 bars in it). So I set a custom value at #0 and I modified it at another point in time (bar #15).

When you have a chart, which has, say, 5500 bars, you need to imagine your 'variables' as if every one of them were an Array with 5500 elements and every index position in the array is a single value to that index-th bar. This is why variables are referred as *Series*, they are not singular values, but series of values.

This is what happens when you plot `close`. You have a big Array, every item is a specific `close` value from a specific bar. But as `close` is changing every time (in other words, Pine will calculate it for you), you have a nice, ever-changing graph.

With custom values, you have to do the calculation yourself and generate a value for that variable for every bar. There are multiple ways to do it, the one I put in above is not the best in Pine's term but for a first approach it is very easy to understand.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, karatedog.
So, I can't use my custom values, It works just with a calculation based on "normal" inputs as "close", "open", "high", etc. 
Am I right?

Comment: No, you can use any custom values. I just wanted to point out that building a custom series "daily" has no meaning, if you are watching a weekly chart. So you want to build your custom series 'time frame independent'.
For that specific case, where you have the daily chart, and you use those exact data you put in your question, I extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your availability, karatedog.
What about if I want insert a new custom value next week. I could formatting it?
Check the screenshot to understand better 
(Image)
[https://i.postimg.cc/tJ6RnHKc/2022-05-18-09-47-50-SPX-4088-84-2-02-ATR-Pullback.jpg]

Comment: @Ale- You need to define "next week". What is it? The 34th candle? or a certain date/time? You need to understand that if you put a value into a variable, defined with `var` at the first candle, and you never modify it and the chart you apply it has  521 candles, the result will be a Series that has 521 elements where all the values are the same (This is done by Pine, you don't have to do anything to get this result).
What you can do is modify the value of that variable when certain conditions happen. Like when "next week" happens.